# UI alignment working different in different browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, image-uploading

i am trying to provide the upload button for field named as logo image.What i am doing is i am displaying the image name and next to image name i am providing the upload button to the user to upload/change image.BUt when i done the layouting for upload button in my system browser it was working fine .U can see the upper part of the attached image , but the same when i try to open in my friends system browser the alignment went horribly wrong.
U can see below part in the attached image.

This snapshot is taken from Chrome browser.
Here is my HTML Code:-

```
<div id="imageName" onclick="getFile()""/>
            <div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
                <input type="file" id="logoImage" name="logoImage"     onchange="sub(this);"/>
                <div id="changeImage" onclick="changeImage()">Click to Upload New Image</div>
            </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript Code:-

```
function changeImage(){
                document.getElementById("logoImage").click();
        }
         function sub(obj){
            var file = obj.value;
            var fileName = file.split("\\");
            document.getElementById("imageName").innerHTML = fileName[fileName.length-1];
          }
```

Here is my CSS:-

```
   #imageName{
   position: absolute;
       left: 170px;
   font-family: calibri;
   width: 150px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   padding-top: 7px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
   -moz-border-radius: 0px;
   border: 0px dashed #BBB; 
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #DDD;

   }

   #changeImage{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 379px;
       left:560px;
   font-family: calibri;
   width: 180px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   padding-top: 7px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
   -moz-border-radius: 0px;
   border: 1px dashed #BBB; 
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #DDD;
   cursor:pointer;
   line-height: .5em;
  }
```

as you can see in the snapshot the above one is working perfectly fine in my system but the same when i try to open in different system browser it was working wierdly.
I tried my best to explain my problem.Let me know if anyone needs more input regarding this.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: you are looking for responsive the page?

Comment: @punitha-- i didn't get what ur point is?

Comment: Check your HTML syntax. There are two errors in the first line alone, that can confuse browsers.